# angularjs directive with promise not changing html element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to translate text of tags using a directive getting the translation dynamically from my server as there is no reliable way to get the culture locale from the browser.

So I use a factory and a promise. The translation messages are correctly extracted from the server and found by the directive but for some reason, the text of the html elements is not changed.

Any clue ?

```
angular.module('myApp.I18N', [], function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('I18N', I18NFactory);
});

function I18NFactory($http, $rootScope) {
    var promise = $http.post('/listlocalizedmessages');
    return {
        translate: function () {
            return promise;
        }
    };
}

var dmfDirectives = angular.module('myApp.directives', []);

dmfDirectives.directive('dmfI18n', ['I18N', function (I18N) {
    return {
     priority: 0,
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: false,
     compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
         if (tAttrs.dmfI18n) {
             I18N.translate().success(function(data, status) {
                var text = data[tAttrs.dmfI18n];
                tElement.text = text ? text : '*no translation*';
            // this logs the correct values but the element on the page is not changed!
                console.log("translate id " + tElement.prop('id') + " " + tAttrs.dmfI18n + " : " + tElement.text);
            });
         }
         return {
             pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {},
             post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {}
         };
     }
 };
}]);
```

I finally found my issue, instead of:

```
tElement.text = text ? text : '*no translation*';
```

I should have written

```
tElement.text(text ? text : '*no translation*');
```

very basic bug...